# Custom Adapter inheriting from DefaultSocialAccountAdapter in django-allAuth throwing error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth to login with Steam in my Django application. I want that when a new user signs up, the user's steam id is also stored in the database. I want to extend the DefaultSocialAccountAdapter and use a custom adapter. Here is my code

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):
        user = super().save_user(request, user, form, commit=False)
        social_account = user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='steam').first()
        if social_account:
            user.steam_id = social_account.uid
            if commit:
                user.save()
        return user
```

When I use this adapter by setting the SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER in my settings.py file, it throws an error stating `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter.new_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sociallogin'`

I also tried to over-ride the new_user method but still got the same error. I tried this:

```
def new_user(self, request):
        user = super().new_user(request)
        user.steam_id = sociallogin.account.uid
        return user
```

But the error remains the same. It shows the error at

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py, line 71, in new_user
        """
        pass
    def new_user(self, request, sociallogin):
        """
        Instantiates a new User instance.
        """
       return get_account_adapter().new_user(request) <--- error on this line
    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
        """
        Saves a newly signed up social login. In case of auto-signup,
        the signup form is not available.
        """
```

I went ahead and looked into the library's codebase and the issue seems to be in the way new_user is being called internally by the library. You can check line 89 here - https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py

The method in the library's code is not passing the sociallogin argument to new_user and I suspect that's what is causing the issue. I could be wrong.

Now I am totally new to Django and I might have missed a trivial thing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed to [`save_user`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/53f5901cad06c12146b6a821ef3b17b4e4a343cc/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py#L91C34-L91C45) method:

> def save_user(self, request, **sociallogin**, form=None):

`save_user` **doesn't have** `commit` parameter.

Your `CustomSocialAccountAdapter` should looks like:

```
class CustomSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    
    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
        user = super().save_user(request, **sociallogin**, form=None)
        social_account = user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='steam').first()
        """
        Not tested, but I think this approach can also be used. Since sociallogin has a property account
        https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/53f5901cad06c12146b6a821ef3b17b4e4a343cc/allauth/socialaccount/models.py#L180)
        if sociallogin.account.provider == "steam":
           ...
        """
        if social_account:
            user.steam_id = social_account.uid
            user.save()
        return user
```

**settings.py:**

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'project.social_adapter.CustomSocialAccountAdapter'
```